# Update feature using protocol don't work in OpenLayers

Tags: protocols, openlayers, updates

I have a WMS layer and I need to update the attributes of one of its features.

So I created a protocol object using OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer, and filtering for the feature ID; then using read() method I get the feature from the response and I have ehat I expect.

```
var protocol = OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(layerFeatureHighlighted, {
  filter: currentFilter
});
```

Then I update the state and the attributes of the feature object:

```
featureObj.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
featureObj.attributes['myAttribute1'] = myValue1;
featureObj.attributes['myAttribute2'] = myValue2;
featureObj.attributes['myAttribute3'] = myValue3;
```

The problem is that when finally I try to save the changes, the changes are not saved into the database:

```
protocol.update(featureObj);
```

How can I save the changes?
Thank
stefano

Comment: Unless there is an error in the console, the error is likely to be server side, I would think. Are you using GeoServer?

Comment: yes, I am using geoserver, but on server side the log doesn't move when I call update() method.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the information you have provided what could be going on.

Comment: yes I understand; but from your point of view should it be correct to make an update() call on a protocol created from a WMS layer?

Comment: I'm really not sure, sorry. It sounds unusual, as WMS doesn't usually produce vector features, but there simply isn't enough information to tell.